# Whats the difference between .asciiz vs .ascii

Tags: mips

I read that .asciiz null terminates the string (appending `\n`?) ... but when looking at the User Data Segment of QtSPIM,

```
User data segment [10000000]..[10040000]
[10000000]..[1000ffff]  00000000
[10010000]    6c6c6548  6f57206f  00646c72  6c6c6548    H e l l o   W o r l d . H e l l 
[10010010]    6f57206f  00646c72  00000000  00000000    o   W o r l d . . . . . . . . . 
[10010020]..[1003ffff]  00000000
```

I don't see a difference?

```
.data
  str1: .asciiz "Hello World" # string str1 = "Hello World"
  str2: .ascii "Hello World" # string str2 = "Hello World"

.text
  .globl main
    main: 
      li $v0, 4 # print_string

      # print(str1)
      la $a0, str1 # load address of str1 into $a0
      syscall

      # print(str2)
      la $a0, str2 # load address of str2 into $a0
      syscall

      j $ra
```

Outputs "*Hello WorldHello World*"

**UPDATE**

What are the implications or when do I use each? `asciiz` sounds like the "proper" method?

Comment: null terminating means adding \0 - the byte with 0 value. ".ascii" is not terminated by macroprocessor

Comment: To see difference, add 3rd str: str2: .ascii "text" and re-check binary dump of segment.

Comment: Ok, so the question will then be when do I use each?

Comment: You read the spec for the routine you are calling and you pass inputs to get the output you want.

Comment: Basically always use `.asciiz` unless your target platform doesn't have an operating system and you want to implement your own control codes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As written by @osgx, ASCIIZ means that the string is terminated by the `\0` (ASCII code 0) NUL character. They are even called [C strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string). To quote from there:

> In computing, a C string is a character sequence terminated with a
>   null character ('\0', called NUL in ASCII). It is usually stored as
>   one-dimensional character array.[dubious – discuss] The name refers to
>   the C programming language which uses this string representation.
>   Alternative names are ASCIIZ (note that C strings do not imply the use
>   of ASCII) and null-terminated string.

Comment: @jiewmeng I would always use asciiz, unless you KNOW you won't need the 0 terminator. OS syscalls normally accept asciiz strings on unix, because unix is/was writen in C.

Comment: @jiewmeng For the missing difference: probably your assembler is trying to align strings on 32/64 bits boundaries. So a 1 character ASCII (non Z) string will be padded with 3x `\0`, making it an ASCIIZ string. Perhaps 4 or 8 char long strings won't show this behaviour. And in general you should put a third string after the ASCII one, to see exactly where the ASCII one ends. Otherwhise the assembler will simply pad the data section with `\0`.