# How to use ascii to prompt input properly in MIPS32

Tags: assembly, mips32

here's my code. I want it to output "Hi, input here: ". But instead, it prints both "Hi, input here: " and "Hello, input here: ". How can I fix that?

```
            .data
str_one:        .ascii      "Hi, input here: \n" 
str_two:        .ascii      "Hello, input here: \n" 

            .text

main:       

    li $v0, 9           #memory allocation syscall
    li $a0, 12
    syscall

    move $s0, $v0          

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str_one        #Prompt string
    syscall

    li $v0, 8          #Read string
    la $a0, ($s0)
    li $a1, 8
    syscall
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between .asciiz vs .ascii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783044/whats-the-difference-between-asciiz-vs-ascii)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't null-terminate your strings.  Use `.asciiz` instead:

```
str_one:        .asciiz      "Hi, input here: \n" 
str_two:        .asciiz      "Hello, input here: \n"
```

Alternately, use an explicit zero:

```
str_one:        .ascii      "Hi, input here: \n" 
                .byte       0
str_two:        .ascii      "Hello, input here: \n" 
                .byte       0
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. The .asciiz thing works. But how does the null-termination work? What would the code look like?

Comment: What would what code look like?  Using `.asciiz` puts a literal zero byte in memory at the end of the string.  The system calls you're calling expect that zero byte to be there to indicate the end of the string.

Comment: ok but you know how you said that adding an explicit 0 would do the trick? Where exactly would I add it? would it look something like this?

Comment: str_one:        .asciiz      "Hi, input here: \n 0"     I'm kinda new this.

Comment: Ohh, okay makes so much sense now. Thanks a lot Carl!

Comment: `.asciiz` places the zero for you without you having to actually write it. So `.asciiz "Hi, input here: \n"` has an invisible zero placed after the line feed.