# Printing a String (assembly)

Tags: assembly, mips

I just started programming `MIPS assembly` and I have a few questions about it.

First, my code:

```
.data
word1: .ascii "Hello"
word2: .ascii " World"
word3: .ascii "!"

.text
main:

#lw $t0, word1
#lw $t1, word2
#lw $t2, word3

li $v0, 4
la $a0, word1
syscall
la $a0, word2
syscall
la $a0, word3
syscall
```

I want to ask why have I a message

```
Runtime exception at 0x0040000c: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010005
```

while I'm trying to load a second word (word2)? (I know that I have not to load a String.)

Secondly, this code's output will be "Hello World! World!!" - word1 word2 word3 word2 word3 word3.

If I comment 10th and 11th line of code (loading other words), the output will be `Hello World!` instead of `Hello`.

Why is it happening? I just want to print one word, not three at once.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: append a ",0" to your strings to tell the OS where the words stop

Comment: In MIPS, you cannot read from misaligned addresses. That's what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the code does not know where to stop. This is why it prints `word1word2word3` when you print just `word1` (Respectively prints `word2word3` when you print just `word2`). I guess there is a terminator in memory (perhaps 0 byte) just after the three words, this is why it stops right after printing them.

What you have to do is to tell the assembler to finish typing after each word by appending a 0 byte to the end of each word as Tommylee2k suggests.

Comment: Okay, but how can I do that? Adding ",0" at the end of string is not helping.

Comment: I am not MIPS expert but I guess you should replace .ascii by .asciiz You can refer to this link for the difference in between these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783044/whats-the-difference-between-asciiz-vs-ascii

Comment: @NoName, with pleasure :)